# Implementing different Y-Axes for ng2-chart gives error "not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "time"; } & Omit<CartesianScaleOptions"

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I'm using ng2-charts on Angular 15 to display a line chart with two sets of data, one of the left side and the other on the right of the Y-Axis. I've followed the following code:

```
  public chart1Data: ChartConfiguration<'line'>['data'] = {
    labels: this.labelData,
    datasets: [
      {
        data: this.loadData,
        label: 'Engine Load',
        fill: false,
        tension: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-l',
      },
      {
        data: this.rpmData,
        label: 'Engine speed (RPM)',
        fill: false,
        tension: 0.5,
        borderColor: 'rgba(255,128,0,1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,128,0,0.3)',
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-r',
      },
    ],
  };

  public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-l',
          position: 'left',
        },
        {
          id: 'y-axis-r',
          position: 'right',
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  public lineChartLegend = true;
```

But the app crashes saying

```
error TS2322: Type '{ id: string; position: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "time"; } & Omit<CartesianScaleOptions, "max" | "min"> & { min: string | number; max: string | number; suggestedMin: string | number; ... 5 more ...; ticks: { ...; }; }> | ... 4 more ... | undefined'.
  Type '{ id: string; position: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "timeseries"; } & Omit<CartesianScaleOptions, "max" | "min"> & { min: string | number; max: string | number; suggestedMin: string | number; ... 5 more ...; ticks: { ...; }; }>'.
    Types of property 'reverse' are incompatible.
      Type '() => { id: string; position: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.

152       yAxes: [
          ~~~~~
```

What could be the issue behind this and how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your current configuration with multiple axes is for version 1.0, which is no longer supported after version 2.0.

While Chart.js does support multiple axes by specifying the `xAxisID` and/or `yAxisID` according to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#default-scales).

Under the `scale` object, specify the key-value pair with the key as the axisID and the value as the configuration for particular axisID.

```
public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions<'line'> = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    'y-axis-l': {
      position: 'left',
    },
    'y-axis-r': {
      position: 'right',
    },
  },
};
```

Reference: [Multi Axis Line Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html)

Comment: This works.  Thanks, this was hard to find how to convert the chart options to the new version